# NASM Stack Error? Simple Multiplication Program

Tags: c, assembly, stack, nasm

I'm learning NASM at the moment and am making a simple program that does multiplication of any user-input variables through shifting and addition.

I've been running into a series of issues: My multiplicand is, for some reason, being given at the maximum data value a word can hold. Furthermore, my answer, if the program should get that far, is almost always wrong (even though I believe my algorithm is correct!).

```
extern printf
extern scanf

section .data
    message: db "Enter your multiplicand: "
    message_L: equ $-message
    message2: db "The number you entered is: %d ", 10, 0
    message2_L: equ $-message2
    message3: db "Enter your multiplier: "
    message3_L: equ $-message3
    message4: db "Your multiplier is: %d ", 10, 0
    message4_L: equ $-message4
    message5: db "The product of this multiplication is: %d ", 10, 0
    mesasge5_L: equ $-message5
    fmt1: db "%d", 0

section .bss
    multiplicand: resw 1
    multiplier: resw 1
    product: resw 1

section .text
    global main
scanInt:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 2
    lea eax, [ebp-2]
    push eax
    push dword fmt1
    call scanf
    mov ax, word[ebp-2]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

main:
    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor edx, edx

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, message
    mov edx, message_L
    int 80h

        call scanInt
        mov word[multiplicand], ax
    mov word[product], ax

    jmp print1
main2:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, message3
    mov edx, message3_L
    int 80h

    call scanInt
    mov word[multiplier], ax

    jmp print2
main3:
    mov ax, word[multiplicand]
    jmp check
check:
    cmp word[multiplier], 2
    jz printAnswer
    ror [multiplier], 1
    shl word[multiplier], 1
    jc carry
    shr word[multiplier], 1
    shr word[multiplier], 1
    shl word[product], 1
    jmp check

carry:
    add word[product], ax
    shr word[multiplier], 1
    clc
    jmp check

endLoop:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

printAnswer:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push word[product]
    push dword message5
    call printf
    add esp, 12
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    jmp endLoop

print1:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push dword[multiplicand]
    push dword message2
    call printf
    add esp, 12
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    jmp main2

print2:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push dword[multiplier]
    push dword message4
    call printf
    add esp, 12
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    jmp main3
```

Comment: Why not just put the code here? My company firewall won't let me get to pastebin. >8v(

Comment: Does it ever work right?  What does it specifically do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem comes from using `word` variables. Making a two-byte buffer on the stack, and calling `scanf` to read into it is almost certainly a problem. Pushing a `word` in 32-bit code is "legal", but likely to cause problems. In one instance, you call `printf` with two variables, and `add esp, 12` afterwards. Make 'em all `dword`s and keep your stack manipulation in four-byte chunks. I think that'll cure most of your problems.

The man pages explicitly suggest not mixing high-level, buffered I/O, functions with low level functions (`printf`, `scanf`, `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()`, etc. are high level functions, `open()`, `read()`, `write()`... and system calls are low level functions). I don't think that this is causing any of your problems, but it can cause weird results. For example, `printf` doesn't print anything until the buffer is flushed. Ending with a linefeed, or using another high level I/O function will flush the buffer. `sys_read`, for example, does not. I'd stick to one or the other.

Good luck!